# How to control external monitor output using cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, video-streaming

I am making a sample application in cocoa in which I have to control video output being send to external monitor connected to a macbook using Mini Display Port/ Mini DVI.

Can anyone suggest me how can I implement it in cocoa?

Thanks in advance for any link, suggestion.

Miraaj

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "control video output" here. If your goal is to manage the display modes and then display full-screen output, you should read [Quartz Display Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Introduction/Introduction.html), which will walk you through most of that.

A simpler solution in many cases, though, is to just create a borderless window using the frame of the the desired screen. You can get information about the available screens in Cocoa using [NSScreen](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Then it's just standard window drawing.